# Unable to match the files

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, glob

I am trying to append my csv files on a weekly basis. There are many files as per weeks but I only have to append the file as per a week such that I can publish the file on a weekly basis which will be a consolidated weekly CSV file.

the files are of this type in naming convention:

```
MidnightJob_Results_1-02-01-2019.csv

MidnightJob_Results_1-03-01-2019.csv

MidnightJob_Results_1-04-01-2019.csv
```

Above format is in `Week-dd-mm-yyyy` format.
Result should be that it matches the files of the week and append them in a single file. However  I am not able to make glob function understand how to achieve that. Please suggest

```
import datetime;
from glob import glob
current_week =(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1]-1)
file_name = "MidnightJob_Results_%d-" % (current_week)
print current_week
print file_name
with open('main.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
for csv in glob("file_name*.csv"):
    if csv == 'main.csv':
        pass
    else:
        for line in open(csv, 'r'):
            singleFile.write(line)
```

Comment: You should not have file_name in a string as it is a variable Give a try to glob("%s*.csv" % (file_name)) This way you will format the string now it looking for literally "file_name" 
as starting name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should format the file_name in glob function as shown below then you should open file in append mode because if file exist you dont want to delete the old file.

```
import datetime;
from glob import glob 
current_week =(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1]-1)
file_name = "MidnightJob_Results_%d-" % (current_week)
print current_week
print file_name
with open('main.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
   for csv in glob("%s*.csv"%(file_name)):
        if csv == 'main.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'a+'):
                 singleFile.write(line)
```